# Power Automate Power BI whenopened trigger

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

Good morning,

I am looking for any solution that could help me analysing how many times is a PowerBI report opened and who opens it. I cannot use the PowerBI analytics.

I was thinking that PowerAutomate might have a Power BI whenopened trigger or something that could work like that.

Does anyone know if it is posible to develope a Power Automate flow that checks that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you could check in the direction of PowerBI API, if there is any such functionality provided. As far as native Power Automate is concerned, I do not think so there is any such trigger to work on. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/)

Comment: Maybe poll the activity events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-activity-events) and setup a pseudo-delta to extract and deal with the new events.  It's fairly straight forward but you'd need to store any processed events so you don't process them again.  You could have a sliding window for the last two days or something to ensure you catch everything and run it every minute or so.